# Azure github action - Could not detect runtime. Please specify using the --runtime flag

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, github-actions

I am trying to deploy code through Github action for Azure Function App but getting runtime error "Could not detect runtime. Please specify using the --runtime flag" I have tried all --runtime node but still no luck. Its a nodejs API and I tried runtime with NODE:12,NODE:14,NODE16 and etc. Following are the available runtime:

```
 "linux": [
    "DOTNETCORE:6.0",
    "DOTNETCORE:5.0",
    "DOTNETCORE:3.1",
    "NODE:16-lts",
    "NODE:14-lts",
    "NODE:12-lts",
    "PYTHON:3.9",
    "PYTHON:3.8",
    "PYTHON:3.7",
    "PHP:8.0",
    "PHP:7.4",
    "RUBY:2.7",
    "RUBY:2.7.3",
    "RUBY:2.6",
    "RUBY:2.6.2",
    "JAVA:11-java11",
    "JAVA:8-jre8",
    "JBOSSEAP:7-java11",
    "JBOSSEAP:7-java8",
    "TOMCAT:9.0-java11",
    "TOMCAT:9.0-jre8",
    "TOMCAT:8.5-java11",
    "TOMCAT:8.5-jre8"

:\myapp-nodejs\  az webapp deployment github-actions add --repo  -g mytest -n mytest --login-with-github
```

> Verified GitHub repo and branch Could not detect runtime. Please specify using the --runtime
> flag.

```
 :\myapp-nodejs\  az webapp deployment github-actions add --repo  -g mytest -n mytest --login-with-github --runtime "NODE:14-lts"
```

> ```
> Verified GitHub repo and branch
> Runtime NODE:14-lts is not supported for GitHub Actions deployments.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this question shortly before I figured out a similar issue myself - the documentation is confusing - maybe try the pipe instead of colon - e.g. `--runtime "NODE|14-lts"` instead of `--runtime "NODE:14-lts"`

Comment: I've just logged some feedback which might explain more thoroughly the issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/21728